# How could Moshe put the avnet on Ahron by himself?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle

How could Moshe Rabbeinu put the avnet on Ahron and his sons by himself (see yoma :ה, or the passuk); the yerushalmi in yoma, when describing how to put on the (32-amah) avnet, says that the cohen in question would stand still while **2** other people walked in circles around him, wrapping it in both directions at the same time - it's a 2 person job, and both parts have to be done simultaneously for it to be wrapped right?

Comment: This question is like asking "How could Babe Ruth put the _avnet_ on _Aharon_ by himself?" unless you edit in proof that _Moshe_ did so.

Comment: Where, in Yoma 5b or the verses it references, does it say that Moshe put the _Avnet_ on each of them **by himself**? I see it saying that he put it on, but not that he did so without help or assistance.

Comment: Vayilvash osam Moshe sure sound like it was Moshe. You could be right, but I'd assume until I knew otherwise that it was just him

Comment: ... even though that assumption creates the difficulty your question is based on?

Comment: It's still a big chidush to say otherwise. I would if I had to, but I'd rather see if anyone knows of an answer first

Comment: @Uber_Chacham I don't know, I upvoted

Answer (score 1):

The Gemorah says that Moshe Rabeinu was 10 amos tall (Berachos 54b) and he could therefor build the mishkan so I assume that he could do other things other people couldn't do.

Comment: Nice. Still, he can't be in 2 places at the same time

Comment: @Uber_Chacham I'd imagine his arms could wrap around Aharon a few times if this midrash is to be taken literally.

Comment: There is still a tzad in the gemara in Shabbos :צב that all of the leviim, including Ahron, were 10 amos tall, and if so they were the same as each other and this wouldn't help at all.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, however 1) that's not the conclusion of the Gemora. 2) Rashi in Berachos 54b learns the drosha specifacally about Moshe, not the Leviim. also the way that the Gemora derived how much his height was can't apply to the leviim (also see Bechoros 44) (even though the Maharsh"a says that he doesn't understand the limud) . However I agree that the havei amina in Shabbos has to be solved... nice.

Comment: @Art (First of all, you missed an e in therefore, and should probably add some commas.) The gemara doesn't have a clear maskana at all, either way, and rashi in brachos, as far as I remember, doesn't say anything about the leviim either way; he's only talking about Moshe over there because that's what the gemara is talking about.

Comment: Also, for some reason people couldn't just wrap it around themselves with both hands (though I don't know exactly why), and whatever reason there is to not do that should lechora apply to Moshe too.

Comment: thank you.  maybe I misunderstood the Gemora coz I looked it over quickly but Rashi davka on that point has a קס"ד meaning that this specifically will change. and later on in Rashi ד"ה וליגמר ממשה I understood him to be dealing with this and the Gemora's kusha subject.

Comment: @Art - Sorry, I didn't understand that

Comment: so the 1st point comes from Halichos Olam in the 2nd shaar chapter 3, that a קא סלקא דעתך (in general- coz rules have exceptions) means that this is going to change, And the  כללי הגמרא of Rav Yosef Karo on the spot.

Comment: the 2nd thing is just how I understood Rashi in the sugya at a quick glance, what does artscroll say?  btw also in the כללים ברש"י at the back of maseches brachos just after the מבוא התלמוד, he discusses קס"ד.